# ROS Answers SE migration: map message

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I've builded an ekf map-based localization but the graphic interface is using matplotlib. Now I want to change to rviz so everithing will be ROS based. My problem is with the map. I can not find how to create a map. I've been trying by looking to gmapping and everithing but it has been impossible to me.

Can you help to solve this problem of how to solve the map message or whatever it is that represents a map in ros?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33265/map-message/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you have a feature/landmark based map if you're using classic EKF-based localization? In that case, the [OccupancyGrid](http://ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) message format used by gmapping and other occupancy grid mapping approaches probably doesn't make much sense.
The easiest option is to publish your feature/landmark locations using [Marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) messages.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2